# Java - Define HashMap type with a method argument

Tags: java, hashmap

I want a method argument to define the class a HashMap will accept. Something along the lines of:

```
private HashMap hashMap = new HashMap();

public boolean createMap(Object obj) {
    return hashMap = new HashMap<String, obj.getClass()>() != null;
}
```

Comment: How about `public boolean <T> createMap() { return hashMap = new HashMap<String, T>() != null; }`? Did you try your example? What is the error you receive?

Comment: this method will always return `true`

Comment: @crush: It expects '>' instead of () after .getClass

Comment: @hoaz It will? Noted.

Comment: @crush: Your example still allows any object type with .put()

Comment: @wolfo9999 What did you supply for `T`?

Comment: Ah. Forgot to add that. Your way works.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't do what you're trying to do: you can't "define the class a `HashMap` will accept" because at runtime a `HashMap` will accept *all* classes.

What you could do, on the other hand, is:

```
private Map<String, ?> map;

public <V> void createMap(Class<V> clazz) {
   map = Collections.checkedMap(new HashMap<String, V>(),
      String.class, clazz);
}
```

...which will actually enforce the restrictions you're trying to create, with reflection.  In this case, your `hashMap` member should have type `Map<String, Object>`, though it will enforce

Comment: It cannot find 'V' in Class<V>

Comment: Did you mean `public <V>`? What is `T` used for in that example?

Comment: Whoops, yes, I meant `<V>`.

Answer (score 0):

define a typed function that accepts the type you desire as value for the map

```
public <T> Map<String, T> checkedStringKeyMap(Class<T> type) {
    return Collections.checkedMap(new HashMap<String, T>(), String.class, type);
}
```

then create your map as follows

```
Map<String, Person> persons = checkedStringKeyMap(Person.class);
```